# AWS - "Signature" for text messages to China

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

We use AWS's SNS service to send text messages with our user's MFA code for logging into our app. In order to send text messages to China, AWS requires us to submit a text template.  The text message must include a "signature". The description of the signature that AWS provides is:

- The signature must be prepended to (i.e. in front of) the SMS message body within square brackets or lenticular brackets depending on the message encoding required for your SMS requests.
- If your message contains special characters such as Unicode text, then you must use lenticular brackets to contain the signature.

  - U+3010 LEFT LENTICULAR BRACKET
  - U+3011 RIGHT LENTICULAR BRACKET
  - Example: 【signature】感谢您注册 {####}，您的一次性密码是 {####}。
- The signature must be between 3-11 characters.
- Only Chinese characters are supported.

**My Question**: what is the signature supposed to look like? My message does not contain unicode text so I'd be using square brackets. Can I just use my company's name for the signature? If my company's name is ACME, could something like this suffice?

`[極致] 你好。這是ACME。您的 MFA 代碼是 {####}`

Translated to english, this would be:

`[ACME] Hi. This is ACME. Your MFA code is {####}`

Comment: The signature should be your recognizable as your company name, for instance, Amazon would use `【Amazon】`, and also note that you would be expected to use  `【】` as the brackets since your message does in fact contain Unicode text.

Comment: That's helpful. I didn't realize Chinese characters were Unicode. Just so I'm certain, if my company's name is ACME, then I can use this【極致】as my signature, correct?  And not【ACME】.  If you want to include your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as "accepted".

Comment: If your company is ACME, then you'd use 【ACME】, if it's wildly known and/or registered as 極致, then use 【極致】.

Comment: Ok, but it says in the description provided by AWS that "Only Chinese characters are supported". Isn't that a bit contradicting? Our company is registered or widely known as ACME, not 極致.  Therefore, I'd like to use【ACME】but I feel it's going to get rejected by AWS for not being in Chinese.

Comment: The full description on [AWS's support page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-sender-ids.html#channels-sms-signature-format-restrictions) says "Chinese/English characters are supported", and early specifically calls out the "Amazon" example.

Comment: I'm onboard now. Sorry for the back and forths.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'm mark it as accepted. Thanks for the help!